# How to work around gradle being broken in docker environments?

Tags: docker, jenkins, gradle

Gradle does not work correctly in a docker environment, it is destined to use too much memory and be killed for using too much memory.

The memory manager gets its snapshots using the following class

https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/process-services/src/main/java/org/gradle/process/internal/health/memory/MemInfoOsMemoryInfo.java

and in particular Gradle determines how much free memory is left by reading /proc/meminfo, which provides an inaccurate reading in a container.

Gradle only kills off Worker Daemons when a request comes in to make a new Worker Daemon with a larger min heap size then is available according to this reading.

Thus, Gradle will keep making workers until it uses up the alotted amount for the container and be killed.

Does anyone have a workaround for this? Don't really understand how this hasn't been a problem for more people. I suppose it only really becomes an issue if your worker daemons can't be reused and so new ones get created, which is the case for me as I have a large number of modules.

I have a temporary workaround wherein I give every jvm spawned a huge -Xms and so it always triggers the min heap size > available and so always removes prior worker daemons, but this is not satisfactory.

-- edit

To preempt some things, --max-workers does not affect the number of Worker Daemons allowed to exist, it merely affects the number which are allowed to be active. Even with --max-workers = 1, it is allowed to have arbitrary many idle Worker Daemons.

Comment: Is the problem that Gradle is using too much memory, that it is spawning too many daemons or that it doesn't see that there is more memory available than it thinks? In any case, have you considered just tuning off the daemon processes with `--no-daemon`? Are you also sure that all your modules need different JVM settings to build? If you could align them, Gradle will not spawn multiple daemons.

Comment: @BjørnVester The problem is that it is using too much memory, as a result of spawning too many daemons without killing off old ones, as a result of incorrectly determining how much free memory is left. I have --no-daemon on, but this only impacts the 'master' daemon, i.e. the daemon which orchestrates everything. Even with --no-daemon on you still get many worker daemons. re whether all my modules need different JVM settings, I am not sure, but one thing Gradle uses to determine whether an existing daemon worker will be compatible is its classloader hierarchy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit - Ignore the below, it somewhat works but I have since patched Gradle by overwriting the MemInfoOsMemoryInfo class and it works a lot better. Will provide a link to the MR onto Gradle soon.

Found a reasonable work around, we listen for the os memory updates, and every time a task is done we request more memory than is determined to be free, ensuring a daemon is stopped.

```
import org.gradle.process.internal.health.memory.OsMemoryStatus
import org.gradle.process.internal.health.memory.OsMemoryStatusListener
import org.gradle.process.internal.health.memory.MemoryManagertask 

task expireWorkers {
    doFirst {
        long freeMemory = 0

        def memoryManager = services.get(MemoryManager.class)
        gradle.addListener(new TaskExecutionListener() {
            void beforeExecute(Task task) {
            }
            void afterExecute(Task task, TaskState state) {
                println "Freeing up memory"
                memoryManager.requestFreeMemory(freeMemory * 2)
            }
        })
        memoryManager.addListener(new OsMemoryStatusListener() {
            void onOsMemoryStatus(OsMemoryStatus osMemoryStatus) {
                freeMemory = osMemoryStatus.freePhysicalMemory
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, unfortunately for me it doesnt work. The gradle daemon is still  almost  always disappearing. I agree with you that it is weird that this hasn't had more attention. Maybe you can edit in your question, that this problem only appears if you limit the container's memory.

Comment: @user1259201 It also didn't work perfectly for me. I have since forked Gradle and written a patch which has been working perfectly! I will provide a link once I have made an MR onto gradle.